# Extract primary and related objects from object relationship result

Tags: apex

I'm trying to get the primary and related objects that are being used of a certain report type. This is my code:

```
 // set new http callout request 
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    
    // use rest api with appropriate parameters 
    req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v51.0/analytics/reports/' + reportId + '/describe');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
    req.setMethod('GET');
    
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    Map<String, Object> resBody = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
    Map<String, Object> reportTypeMetadata_2 = (Map<String, Object>) resBody.get('reportTypeMetadata');
    
    List <Object> objectRelationships = (List <Object>) reportTypeMetadata_2.get('objectRelationships');
```

If I were to `System.debug('test: ' + objectRelationships);` I would get a long line like this as my output:

`({label=Assets, primaryEntityField=0725f00000RZQrK, relatedObjects=({label=Activities, relatedEntity=Activity, relatedEntityJoinField=WhatId}, etc....})`

But from all this, I only need the label and the related object label(s). I have tried a number of methods like `objectRelationships.get('label')` or traversing through a loop , but nothing worked. How can I isolate and extract the info that I want from this result?

Note: I had initally tried to have `objectRelationships` as a map but I was running into errors there as well so I decided to put it into a list

Comment: Rather than just logging the value out this way, you would probably be able to understand the structure better by logging `JSON.serialize(objectRelationships)`. This way you will clearly see what is an array (square brackets) and what is a Map (a.k.a. object, with curly brackets).

Comment: Ok so I did that, and it seems that the outermost bracket is a square bracket which means its a map. And then the inner brackets are curly meaning its an array. But I have tried putting it into a map and was running into errors there too.

Comment: Opposite: square = array, curly = map

Comment: Oops, yeah I see that. But I still don't get how I would be able to extract the parts that I want.

Comment: Cast to required type (`List<Object>` for array or `Map<String, Object>` for Object and the required type (Integer, String, Double or Boolean) for primitive values. It comes down to casting to the right thing, calling `get` in a Map to get a named property and casting again.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I'm confused on how and where to cast it properly. If I do ```System.debug('test: ' + (Map<String, Object>)obj.get('label'));``` in my loop, I still get the same error as before.

Comment: You have an array first with maps inside... from what you said...

Comment: Right but I just tried both to see and neither worked.